# Regexp to parse expression

Tags: php, regex, vb6

I am developing an utility app in VB6 for my use to parse code and extract all the expression leaving the code semantic. At first I am focusing on PHP and VB6.

For example, if I pass this code in PHP:

```
if($myvar ==0 || $myvar < 0){

echo "$myvar is less that 0";
}
```

The regular expression should be able to give me just two lines
`$myvar == 0 || $myvar < 0` and `echo "$myvar is less that 0";`.

[EDIT]

Although there might be nested `ifs`, i also want to parse it, displaying it in the result that it was nested.

Also i want it to parfse functions too

```
public function myfoo($somevar,$myvar,$yourvar){

$temvar= $somevar*2
$temvar= convertToString($myvar,$yourvar)
return $temvar

}
```

in this case it will extract
`myfoo($somevar,$myvar,$yourvar)`  `$temvar= $somevar*2`  `$temvar= convertToString($myvar,$yourvar)`  `return $temvar`

**Two questions**

1. How do I figure out regexp to parse such text?
2. Is there any free library that can do this?

Comment: I don't understand what the rules are for extracting that text. Is it "everything on a line before a `{`" and "everything between `{` and `}`"? If it's something like this, can braces be nested in your code? Do you want to use VB6 to parse PHP code, or do you want to do this in your IDE?

Comment: @ Tim Pietzcker, i added more info. am developing th application in vb6. it will be used to parse php and vb6 code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check radsoftware.com.au for their very handy regular expression tester

check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/vb.html for info about handling regular expressions in a VB6 app (VB6 doesn't have native regex capability like.net)